# Отправка письма с вложенным файлом

Tags: php, email

Здравствуйте, у меня есть код отправки письма:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
}
$address = "почта";
$tema    = "Тема";
$mes     = "От кого: $name \n Адрес отправителя: $email \n Сообщение: $message";
$go      = mail($address, $tema, $mes, "Content-type:text/plain; charset=windows-1251\r\nFrom:$email");
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы к письму было прикреплено изображение... Саму форму я написал, а что надо сюда добавить для отправки изображения как вложенного файла?

Comment: Что за бред?
Файл не вкладывается в письмо, вы просто указываете в сообщении письма ссылку на адрес файла в сети, никаких вложений mail() не передает

Answer (score 2):

Как это не вкладывается, на php.net (который должен быть главным примером и источником) даже [пример](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#105661) есть.